# Webstorm 8.0.5 Issue regarding "Unresolved method or function"

Tags: node.js, express, webstorm, body-parser

I'm rather new to Webstorm and Node.  During my explorations of the 8.0.5 iteration of Webstorm, I've setup a vanilla Node.js/Express/EJS project, to which I've made no code changes.

So, my questions refer to the code generated automatically by Webstorm for a Node.js/Express/EJS project.

The issue I'm facing, is that in the project file app.js, Webstorm has identified "urlencoded()" in the following line of code as an unresolved method or function:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

I've been careful to include the following external libraries in the vanilla project:

- body-parser-DefinitelyTyped
- express-DefinitelyTyped
- Node.js v0.10.32 Core Modules

When I right click in the code area for app.js, I can select "Use JavaScript Library" to see that, indeed, my external libraries are selected.

My questions:

1)  What would cause Webstorm to identify `urlencoded()` as unresolved, given the external libraries I've included?

2)  How do I fix this?

For convenience, I've also created a [screenshot](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/servlet/JiveServlet/download/5525695-20825/ScreenShot.tiff).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this is a bug in WebStorm (including the latest iteration, at the time of this writing: 9.0.1).

For details, please see:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14072

Also, at the above site, one can up-vote this issue to increase its urgency, if desired.

Comment: Fixed in 2016.1.1 (145.597).

Answer (score 1):

The latest body-parser version that is not affected by this issue is v.1.3.1